# Error when queing build with sonarqube. Unauthorized

Tags: tfs, sonarqube, azure-devops

I am trying to integrate sonarqube with TFS, I created a build definition with only one step, the sonar qube integration, based on this tutorial:

1. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/08/24/build-tasks-for-sonarqube-analysis/

I know my sonarqube is already setup, because I can access it through the browser and the database is correctly setup.

However I am getting this error:

```
14:45:53.684  Default properties file was not found at C:\BuildAgents\DefaultBuildAgent\5\.sonarqube\bin\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
14:45:53.762  Updating build integration targets...
14:45:53.84  Fetching analysis configuration settings...
Unhandled Exception: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address)
at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(String address)
at SonarQube.TeamBuild.PreProcessor.WebClientDownloader.Download(String url)
at SonarQube.TeamBuild.PreProcessor.SonarWebService.GetProperties(String projectKey, String projectBranch)
at SonarQube.TeamBuild.PreProcessor.TeamBuildPreProcessor.FetchArgumentsAndRulesets(ISonarQubeServer server, ProcessedArgs args, TeamBuildSettings settings, IDictionary`2& serverSettings, AnalyzerSettings& analyzerSettings)
at SonarQube.TeamBuild.PreProcessor.TeamBuildPreProcessor.DoExecute(ProcessedArgs args)
at SonarQube.TeamBuild.PreProcessor.TeamBuildPreProcessor.Execute(String[] args)
at SonarQube.TeamBuild.PreProcessor.Program.Main(String[] args)
Pre-processing succeeded.
Unexpected exit code received from batch file: 255
******************************************************************************
Finishing task: SonarQubePreBuild
******************************************************************************
Task SonarQubePreBuild failed. This caused the job to fail. Look at the logs for the task for more details.
******************************************************************************
Finishing Build
******************************************************************************
Worker Worker-28c6fdb7-9350-4b65-bbba-0e9aab5e0e83 finished running job 28c6fdb7-9350-4b65-bbba-0e9aab5e0e83
```

Comment: What are the permissions on your project? Does 'Anyone' have permission to Browse and Execute Analysis? Does the user whose credentials you're using?

Comment: I am a newbie in sonar but I am experimented user in TFS, can you please explain me more in detail, according to this url: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/08/24/build-tasks-for-sonarqube-analysis/, it says that in the user and password I can fill anything example: anonymous/anonymous and thats exactly what I did, at the moment there are no users in sonarqube, just the admin

Comment: This should help: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Authorization#Authorization-ProjectPermissions

Comment: I am not sure exactly what to do, I created the project, I added global permissions, etc, and still get the same error.

Comment: Is your SonarQube server on-premise?

Comment: yes its onpremises

Comment: Can you try with default admin credentials? the username and password is both "admin".

Comment: yes I tried, but not working

Comment: Try to add a new user and add to admin group, then update SonarQube endpoint (Generic service endpoint) username and password, then try again. (Add user: Go to SonarQube site: e.g. Http://[machine name]:9000=>Click Log on to login=>Click Administration=>Security=>User=>Create User=>Then go to group page (Security=>Group) to add that user)

Comment: Is there a solution to this problem yet? I have the exact same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the authentication token in the SonarQube service endpoint in TFS: [click!](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/SonarQube+Endpoint)

To obtain a user token in SonarQube follow [these steps](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/User+Token)

Be sure the sonar.login and sonar.password properties in SonarQube.Analysis.xml are commented out, otherwise the token won't be used.

Comment: dans sonarQube, you go to user Account Tab -> My Account -> Security and then you generate a new token to use in your TFS EndPoint